# Error adding vfp table to existing

Tags: variables, visual-foxpro

I copied a new version of a table into an existing vfp installation and when it then tries to access that table it comes up with a variable not found error. The old version and new version of the table appear to have the same structure. Why could this happen? Does the dbc need to be updated in some way if I copy a new version of the table in. The structure is the same, but the data in it is different.

I copied the table in in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was the table that you've copied in "freed" from it's previous DBC before copying? If not, as soon as you attempt to USE it in the new location then I believe VFP will try to locate the DBC that it belongs to.

If you believe the table structure to be identical then you might be better off leaving the existing one in place and just ZAPping it to clean it out then appending the records from the other copy... of course you might need to temporarily switch off any INSERT triggers or row-level validation if you've got anything clever happening therein such as updating a "last modified" field. AutoInc fields will also need to be handled with care too, but it doesn't sound like this is something you're expecting to do on a regular basis so shouldn't be too onerous as a one-off exercise.

Answer (score 1):

If the DBC in the same folder as the table? If not, are they in the same relative position on the two different drives? If not, you'll get errors, though I wouldn't expect "Variable not found."

Did you bring along the FPT and CDX for the new file? Again, that's not the error I would expect, but failure to do so would cause problems.

Assuming all that is right, what's the actual line of code that's failing?

Comment: I wasn't doing it as part of a program, just executing commands 1 by 1 in VFP. However, it seems to be the DBC is not linked that causes the error.